# cups rejects printing pdf files with 'filter error' probalbly due to a too-long-title

Tags: pdf, printing, debian, cups

My system is Debian 3.16.7. Today I rendered a printing job (a paper names *Distributed Representations of Words and Phrases and their Compositionality*) using cups to my Kyocera fs-1041 printer. However the printer reject to print with an error message of 'Filter failed' at the browser control panel of cups.

Inside my /var/cups/error_log it says:

```
    E [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details.
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] The following messages were recorded from 12:36:21 PM to 12:36:27 PM
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Adding start banner page "none".
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Adding end banner page "none".
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] File of type application/pdf queued by "root".
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] hold_until=0
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Queued on "Kyocera_FS-1041" by "root".
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] time-at-processing=1474194981
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] 3 filters for job:
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] gstoraster (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-raster, cost 99)
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertokpsl (application/vnd.cups-raster to printer/Kyocera_FS-1041, cost 0)
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] job-sheets=none,none
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] argv[0]="Kyocera_FS-1041"
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] argv[1]="225"
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] argv[2]="root"
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] argv[3]="Distributed Representations of Words and Phrases and their Compositionality - 5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf"
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] argv[4]="1"
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] argv[5]="CaBrightness=0 PageSize=Letter MediaType=PrnDef EngineSpeed=Off CaContrast=0 number-up=1 job-uuid=urn:uuid:a19e56db-80b7-307d-4359-b8a1c32c90f5 job-originating-host-name=localhost time-at-creation=1474194981 time-at-processing=1474194981"
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00225-001"
    ...
    <!-envps>
    ...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster"
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 4664)
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 4665)
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertokpsl (PID 4666)
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb (PID 4667)
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Loading USB quirks from "/usr/share/cups/usb".
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Loaded 113 quirks.
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Printing on printer with URI: usb://Kyocera/FS-1041?serial=NZF2X06371
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] *** buffer overflow detected ***: Kyocera_FS-1041 terminated
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] ======= Backtrace: =========
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x731af)[0x7f525aaf11af]
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7f525ab76cf7]
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xf6f10)[0x7f525ab74f10]
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Kyocera_FS-1041[0x406c87]
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f525aa9fb45]
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Kyocera_FS-1041[0x40799d]
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] ======= Memory map: ========
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] 00400000-00430000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 3541254                            /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertokpsl
    ...
    <!-Memory map->
    ...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] PID 4666 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertokpsl) crashed on signal 6.
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] libusb_get_device_list=8
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] STATE: +connecting-to-device
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] STATE: -connecting-to-device
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Printer found with device ID: MFG:Kyocera;MDL:FS-1041;CLS:PRINTER;SN:NZF2X06371;CID:KY_KPSL_MonoPersonal; Device URI: usb://Kyocera/FS-1041?serial=NZF2X06371
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Device protocol: 2
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Sending data to printer.
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Sent 0 bytes...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] PID 4664 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Color Manager: Calibration Mode/Off
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-Kyocera_FS-1041)
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_Kyocera_FS_1041
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.Get(ProfilingInhibitors)
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-Kyocera_FS-1041)
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_Kyocera_FS_1041
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Calling GetProfileForQualifiers(Gray.PrnDef.600dpi...)
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Found profile /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/Kyocera_FS_1041_Gray__
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Profile.Get(Filename)
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Use profile filename: ''
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Color Manager: ICC Profile: 
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Ghostscript command line: /usr/bin/gs -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOINTERPOLATE -sDEVICE=cups -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=%stdout -r600x600 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=612 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=792 -dcupsBitsPerColor=8 -dcupsColorOrder=0 -dcupsColorSpace=3 -dcupsCompression=1 -scupsPageSizeName=Letter -I/usr/share/cups/fonts -c '<</.HWMargins[12.000000 8.000000 12.000000 16.000000] /Margins[0 0]>>setpagedevice' -f -_
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
    ...
    <!-envps->
    ...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] envp[30]="AUTH_INFO_REQUIRED=none"
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Start rendering...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Processing page 1...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Processing page 2...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Waiting for read thread to exit...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] PID 4667 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Processing page 3...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Processing page 4...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Processing page 5...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Processing page 6...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Processing page 7...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Processing page 8...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Processing page 9...
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] Rendering completed
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] PID 4665 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) exited with no errors.
    D [18/Sep/2016:12:36:27 +0200] [Job 225] End of messages
```

Have searched several issues and questions like [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234800) or [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=660420) and so on, i could still not find a way to get rid of this problem.

Strangely, right now the cups' test page or doc files created by LibreOffice etc. are still able to be printed.

So i guess it may be caused by the pdf file itself and start to hack in the formated file and finally realized that a too-long `/Title` field will cause this problem. After altering this field from "Distributed Representations of Words and Phrases and their Compositionality" to just "test", it really works!!

But it's still unknown why this long `/Title` field will cause a filter error, could anyone please suggest an answer or post me a link about how do filters behave with a pdf file?

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix it, you need to open PPD file for your printer in text editor.
Find a line `*cupsFilter: "application/vnd.cups-raster 0 /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertokpsl"`and change `rastertokpsl` to `rastertokpsl-fixed`. After that, save it and open a terminal.
Enter `sudo nano /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertokpsl-fixed` in terminal and hit Enter.

Paste this content in :

```
#!/bin/bash
jobname=$(echo $3 | egrep -o '[[:alnum:]]' | tr -d '\n' | tail -c 20)
path=/usr/lib/cups/filter
$path/rastertokpsl "$1" "$2" "$jobname" "$4" "$5"
```

and press Ctrl+O. Now you can set up printer in Settings using this PPD.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answering. Since the posting of this question it has been so long till you give me this valuable advice. I haven't found any rastertokpsl file under /usr/lib/cups/filter/ but i did find [this](https://github.com/lurepheonix/rastertokpsl-fs-1040) driver that contains it based on your suggestion. Hopfully that driver will work!

Comment: The [Patch](https://github.com/lurepheonix/rastertokpsl-fs-1040) you pointed on your comment  basically does the same things, however pay attention the PPD file it fixed is the Russian version.